# Winforms. Why do the values in the array(contains CheckBox.Checked values) come from the end?

Tags: c#, winforms

I get some troubles, how to fix this?

There's code:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<bool> propertiesList = new();

    foreach (CheckBox checkBox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        propertiesList.Add(checkBox.Checked);

    int[] properties = new int[propertiesList.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        properties[i] = propertiesList[i] ? 1 : 0;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", properties));
}
```

In MessageBox I got this, but it must be 1, 1, 1, 0, 0:

[image]

Comment: Seems no need for all that list and array business. Why not just `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Select(c => c.Checked ? "1" : "0")));` and perhaps add `.Reverse()` or `.OrderBy(c => c.Name)` in as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Form1.Designer.cs file. The form design code is written there. The CheckBoxes here are created in the same order as they were added to the form, but at the end they are added to the Controls collection in reverse order.

```
this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox3);
this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox2);
this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
```

Controls collection can be processsed reversely, or the result can be reversed. However, it would be better to add values to the list manually by name, or keep a sorted collection of references directly to CheckBoxes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How can I process them in reverse order? (This is my first experience with Controls, so I don't quite understand all the nuances of working with it yet). It would be nice to just know about it, and so I'd probably better use the second method described by you

Comment: For example you can reverse collection in foreach `Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Reverse()`.